# Error: Failed to find request token in session for passport-twitter

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js, passport-twitter

Following is the error I am getting when using `passport-twitter` -

```
Error: Failed to find request token in session
    at Strategy.OAuthStrategy.authenticate (/MYPROJECT/node_modules/passport-twitter/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:142:54)
    at Strategy.authenticate (/MYPROJECT/node_modules/passport-twitter/lib/strategy.js:85:40)
    at attempt (/MYPROJECT/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:337:16)
    at Object.authenticate [as handle] (/MYPROJECT/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:338:7)
    at next_layer (/MYPROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/MYPROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at /MYPROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:205:24
    at Function.proto.process_params (/MYPROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:269:12)
    at next (/MYPROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:199:19)
    at next (/MYPROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:38)
```

Following is the [Scotch Twitter Signup](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-twitter) tutorial I implemented, `FB signup` is  working fine.

**FYI**-

I checked the configuration multiple times at twitter and everything seems ok to me(callbackURL, key, secret etc.)

I checked the following [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346458/error-failed-to-find-request-token-in-session) but no luck.

My development URL is like - `http://192.XXX.XXX.XX:PORT_NUMBER`

Following is my `app.js` [app.js](http://pastebin.com/Q9CN6Uvf)

Following is my `passport.js` [passport.js](http://pastebin.com/BggGkzNw)

Following is my `model.js`  [buyer.js](http://pastebin.com/uN59T636)

Let me know what I am doing wrong if any as I am completely lost with the error now :(

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting that. This helped me:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter/issues/45#issuecomment-66934259

It was calling from localhost:300 but had my callback URL set to 127.0.0.1:3000. I changed my callback URL to localhost:3000 and the problem was solved.